# Can one assume get-method to be thread-safe if not otherwise noted?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, getmethod

Can one generally assume thread-safety for get-methods if not otherwise noted in the documentation of a method? Or is it the other way round that one should never assume thread-safety if not otherwise noted? What do you think?

**Edit**:

Assume a class

```
class InfoClass {
  public:
    void Init();
    int  GetInfo();
    void Free();
};
```

Calling `Init()` once, `GetInfo()` from a threaded context, and `Free()` after the threaded operations have ended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thread-safety **always** requires extra work, so the only thing you can safely assume is the opposite - in the absence of a direct support the thread-safety is **not** supported.

Explanation:

Suppose you have a `get`ter for a simple 64-bit `long long` and are running on a 32-bit architecture. While the computer is fetching the second half of that long 64-bit value (having just been done with the first half) another thread updates that second half and now what you have is an inconsistency - thus it's not thread-safe.

**Edit** (to match the edit in the question):

(side note - the way you presented your class is making it unusable as all the members are private)

If you do not have **any** access methods that change the state of your class after it's been built then you *can* assume thread-safety. But it's still a sloppy slope as later on someone who doesn't know about your assumption may add a `set`ter to the class and have a wonderful journey in a random-error debugging experience ;)

Comment: Uups, corrected the *private* thingy. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Alternatively you can use a `struct` instead of `class` as all the members of a `struct` are `public` by default

Answer (score 4):

I think you should assume the method is `not thread-safe` if not said otherwise.

Actually I don't see any reason to assume a method is `thread-safe` by default.

Answer (score 2):

A get method COULD be thread-safe, but again not necessarily. If there is a class:

```
class A {
    int value;

    int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    void processValue() {
        value += 2;
        value = value*2;
    }
}
```

In the above code, `getValue` is clearly not thread-safe as it might be called when another thread is at the second line in `processValue` and hence the variable `value` being in an inconsistent state. So, the getter here is re-entrant (again, this might not be so), but still not thread safe.

As others have mentioned on this thread, unless specified, assume that it is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable is getting updated using `set` method when you call `get` method the result will be garbage. So unless specified, thread safety can not be assumed.